# How can I get it to validate my inputfield

Tags: validation, laravel-5.8

The inputfield dosn't get validated it make a postrequest anyway wether or not the validations is valid

I have watched and followed serial youtube vidos, without any lock. 
I have also tried to read the documentation but I couldn't find the error

MY Controller:

```
 public function changepassword(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'passwordA' => 'string', 'min:8', 'same:passwordB',
            'passwordB' => 'string', 'min:8',
        ]);
    }
```

My view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Profil</div>

                <div class="card-body">

  <form method="POST" action="userprofile">
                @csrf 
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Username</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" placeholder="{{ $user->email }}" readonly>
  </div>
      </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="{{ $user->firstname }} {{$user->surname}}" readonly>
    </div>
      </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phonenumber</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="{{ $user->telephonenr }}" readonly>
    </div>
      </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Rest password</label>
    </div>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="passwordA" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">New-Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="password" class="form-control @error('passwordA') is-invalid @enderror" id="passwordA" name="PasswordA">
    @error('passwordA')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
   @enderror
    </div>
      </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="passwordB" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Type again</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="password" class="form-control @error('passwordB') is-invalid @enderror" id="passwordB" name="PasswordB">
    @error('passwordB')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
   @enderror
    </div>
      </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
</form>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I was expected to validate the input and when I dosn't fit to the validating criteria the it should show the validation error

Comment: I found one error the password was not Capitalized. But it still not validate All validaton criteria only the first